# The property of connectedness depends on the topology

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I came across the definition of connectedness and it has been stated as

> **Definition:** A topological space $(X, \tau)$ is connected if the only subsets which are both open and closed are $\varnothing$ and $X$.

Does this mean that the same set $X$ might or might not be connected depending upon how $\tau$, its topology, is defined? Obviously, the trivial topology is always connected. However, is there any theorem which says something about the connectedness of a non-trivial topology $(X, \tau')$ provided we know that there is a disconnected topology on the same set $X$ namely $(X, \tau)$?

Put in other words, is it possible to choose topologies on a set $X$ in a non-trivial manner depending upon whether we need a connected, or disconnected topology?

Comment: Consider the discrete topology?

Comment: Absolutely, yes.  Connectedness is a topological property, so it depends not on the underlying set but  on the way we choose to topologize that set.  The real line $\Bbb R$ is connected in the usual topology, but it is disconnected in the [lower limit topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology).  Every space  is connected in the trivial topology but (if it has more than one point) disconnected in the discrete topology.

Comment: @MJD It's amazing that it is totally disconnected! This is such a bizzaro world!

Comment: A topological space is just a pair $(X,T)$ where $T$ is a collection of some or all of the subsets of $X,$  where there are some restrictive properties that $T$ must satisfy: (1). $\emptyset \in T$ and $X\in T.$ (2). If $F\subseteq T$ then $\bigcup F\in T$. (3). If $G\subseteq T$ and if $G$ is $finite$ then $\bigcap G\in T.$

Comment: I am actually reading Introduction to Topology by Mendelsen. Question is not so much about what a topological space is. It is about the amazing fact that the exact same set with a different topology can be totally disconnected. As @MJD mentioned, one example is that of real line. While it is connected in the usual topology, it is *totally disconnected* in the lower limit topology which to me is a really bizarre fact because I am very much used to thinking that the real line is connected. The revelation that it also depends on the topology happened recently through the answers in this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your title, regarding whether connectedness depends on the topology, notice that when the concept of a "topology" is defined, at the same time the concept of "open" is also defined:

> Given a topology $\tau$ on a set $X$, and given a subset $U \subset X$, to say "$U$ is open" means "$U \in \tau$".

This is like a dictionary entry: everywhere you see the phrase "$U$ is open", you may use your dictionary and substitute that phrase with "$U \in \tau$", assuming of course that a topology $\tau$ has been given.

So, you can rewrite the definition of connectedness in this way. First, introduce a variable:

> **Definition:** A topological space $(X, \tau)$ is connected if the only subsets $U$ such that $U$ is both open and closed are $U=\varnothing$ and $U=X$.

Next, apply the definition of closed:

> **Definition:** A topological space $(X, \tau)$ is connected if the only subsets $U$ such that both $U$ and $X-U$ is open are $U=\varnothing$ and $U=X$.

And, finally,

> **Definition:** A topological space $(X, \tau)$ is connected if the only subsets $U$ such that $U \in \tau$ and $X-U \in \tau$ are $U=\varnothing$ and $U=X$.

And now it is crystal clear: the definition of connectedness depends quite heavily on $\tau$.

So at this stage it should not be a surprise that when you swap $\tau$ out for some other randomly chosen topology $\tau'$ on $X$, the question of whether $(X,\tau')$ is connected is quite independent of the question of whether $(X,\tau)$ is connected.

Comment: It is amazing to learn that you can actually have a topology defined on the set of reals that makes it totally disconnected, as is the case with lower limit topology pointed out by @MJD. I am transitioning from a lower undergrad analysis book (Stephen Abbott's book) which deals with one variable real analysis, to point set topology (Mendelsen's book). Abbott assumes the usual topology for real line. Now that I am studying point set topology, I couldn't fathom that a *finer* topology on reals can be defined to make it totally disconnected

Comment: because a lot of my intuition is still based off of one variable analysis on the real line which assumes the usual topology and in that topology, the real line is connected.

Comment: Another totally disconnected topology on $\mathbb R$ is the very finest possible topology of them all: the discrete topology, in which every subset is open.

Comment: That's another thing I learn today. Every discrete topology is totally disconnected!